# Infinite sum of Combinations

Tags: limits, binomial-theorem

[image]

we can write $\frac{1}{4^n}$ as $\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$
then I used  Stirling’s approximation for factorial for Simplification, but calculation became complicated, then I tried to use L' hopital's rule Rule again the calculation became complicated, Is there a different approach to this problem if so please do explain

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}\frac{1}{4^{n}} = \frac{1}{4^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} = \frac{1}{4^{n}}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} + \frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}\bigg)=\frac{1}{4^{n}}\bigg(\frac{4^{n}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}\bigg)$$

Using the approximation $\displaystyle\binom{2n}{n} \approx \frac{4^{n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$, derived from Stirling's Approximation:

$$\Longrightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4^{n}}\bigg(\frac{4^{n}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}\bigg) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4^{n}}\bigg(\frac{4^{n}}{2}+\frac{4^{n}}{2\sqrt{\pi n}}\bigg)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n}}\bigg)=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Could u explain me, What did u do in the first step? where u made the summation from n to 2n?

Comment: Because the binomial coefficients are symmetrical $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$, the sum from $0$ to $n$ is equal to half the sum from $0$ to $2n$, and we also have to add half of the central coefficient because it only appears once.